# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const defaultProtectedRouteProps: ProtectedRouteProps = {
    isAuthenticated: this.props.state.session.isAuthenticated,
    authenticationPath: '/',
};
```

```
export interface ProtectedRouteProps extends RouteProps {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    authenticationPath: string;
}
```

Getting the error on my props, does anyone know why ts is yelling at me?